# Nested if in lightning design

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

How to use nested if in style css Lightning Design System.
this is working fine

```
<div class="{!v.case.Priority == 'Closed' 
                     ? 'row closed' : 'row '}" >
```

But when I write the same for nested if condition it doesn't work

```
<div class="{!v.case.Priority == 'Closed' 
                 ? 'row closed' : v.case.Priority == 'New' 
                 ? 'row new' : 'row '}" >
```

Comment: If you don't find a solution to your code, you could try adding a wrapper and instead of doing v.case.Priority do v.caseWrapper.parsedPriority.

Comment: Do parentheses help i.e. `v.case.Priority == 'Closed' ? 'row closed' : (v.case.Priority == 'New' ? 'row new' : 'row ')`?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't nest the terniary operator, then concatenate two (or more) of them. Try something like this:

```
"{! v.case.Priority == 'Closed' ? 'row closed' : '' + 
   v.case.Priority == 'New' ? 'row new' : 'row ' }"
```

One other option (which I haven't tried) would be to use the function version of the terniary operator - `if(condition, true, false)` and see if that is able to be nested.

Reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_overview.htm)